# How to force Rails 4 to use old-style hash syntax

Tags: hash, ruby-on-rails-4, hashrocket

I've just upgraded an old project to Rails 4 and I've just realized that it has upgrade the `schema.rb` using the new-style hash syntax. I suppose Rails is gonna use this syntax for all its generators.

How can I, friendly, say to Rails that I prefer the old-style syntax for hashes?

Comment: This is a Ruby question and not specific to Rails. However, there is no built in way to disable the short hash syntax.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot why do you say _"This is a Ruby question and not specific to Rails"_?

Comment: Ruby is the language, Rails is a web app framework. The short hash syntax is a feature of the language, not of the framework. You tagged the question with ruby-on-rails and not with ruby. And your question asked that of Rails. Just trying to help... pedantically.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot I see, thanks for the clarification. But as I'm blaming to one of the Rails code generators as the responsible of this choice I think that _"This is a Rails question and not specific to Ruby"_ ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`schema.rb` is created by `rake db:migrate` command. As per my knowledge, it will be hard to suggest the old-style syntax for hashes to Rails. BUT nothing is impossible, you can play around with `rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb` file. The only problem is when you upgrade the rails gem next time it will override.

This old-style syntax to new-style syntax for hashes was done in [Dump schema using new style hash](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b485b8a06626be3a1b8a2037092a9dda1b28e8a4) commit.

Comment: Even if this is not a solution to my problem I think this is the correct, and sad, answer :/. Thanks for the link to the commit.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly an answer to your question, but it might help nevertheless.

If you use vim, this will allow you to toggle between the old & new syntax ([source](http://dhruvasagar.com/2013/11/26/vim-toggle-ruby-hash-syntax)):

```
function! s:RubyHashSyntaxToggle() range
  if join(getline(a:firstline, a:lastline)) =~# '=>'
    silent! execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . 's/[^{,]*[{,]\?\zs:\([^: ]\+\)\s*=>/\1:/g'
  else
    silent! execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . 's/[^{,]*[{,]\?\zs\([^: ]\+\):/:\1 =>/g'
  endif
endfunction
command! -bar -range RubyHashSyntaxToggle <line1>,<line2>call s:RubyHashSyntaxToggle()
noremap <Leader>rh :RubyHashSyntaxToggle<CR>
```

At max it will take you 3 keystrokes to get the schema the way you want. It is not automatic, but as a counterpart it will work on any file, not just on the schema.

You could invoke the substitution every time you save a file (I do that to remove extra spaces at the ends of lines).

And if you don't use vim, these regexes probably be adapted to other editors.

Comment: What I'm worry about is that looks like from now on the Rails code generators are gonna use the new syntax for any code generated, I would like to have an option to tell it: please use the old syntax :), the same way I can tell it to use my favourite test framework. So I don't need to be cleaning up all the time. But thanks for the trick anyway.